# Virtual function call from a normal function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

```
class base
{
public:
    void virtual func(){cout<<"base";}
    void check()
    {
        func();
    }
};
class derived: public base
{
public:
    void func(){cout<<"dervied";}
};
int main()
{
    base *obj = new derived();
    obj->check();
    return 0;
}
```

Above code prints derived on the console.
Now, I understand the concept of virtual functions but I'm unable to apply it here. In my understanding whenever we call a virtual function, compiler modifies the call to `"this->vptr->virtualfunc()"` and that's how most heavily derived's class function gets invoked. But in this case, since `check()` is not a virtual function, how does the compiler determine that it needs to invoke `func()` of derived?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how does the compiler determine that it needs to invoke func() of derived?

In the same exat way - by invoking `this->vptr->virtualfunc()`. Recall that `this` belongs to the *derived* class even inside the base class, because each derived class *is a* base class as well, so the same way of accessing virtual functions works for it too.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the way you said, by using the `vptr` in the class member. It knows the function is `virtual`, therefore it knows it has to call it through the virtual function table.